# How to hide certain columns for a user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On a shared Google spreadsheet:

I don't want a **specific** user in my domain to view columns with sensitive data, but this person should still be able to edit the rest of the spreadsheet.

I tried creating a 'master' spreadsheet and using importrange to bring the data into a 'shared' sheet, but once I edit any cell in the shared spreadsheet, importrange no longer works as the sheet is emptied out.

Is there a quick way to do this, maybe using scripting?

Comment: I think you can use a protected sheet. Did you ask here - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/spreadsheets ... Stackoverflow is code related, so your question is not a good fit. Good luck.

Comment: hey, thanks, I tried searching there but no luck. I'll look into protected sheets. I was thinking if there is a way to do this via the API, like testing for the user's email address like Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()

Comment: The API just lets you automate, but you are not looking to automate, you want to control access. If what you want is possible, then there will be a way to do it with the spreadsheet directly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After some research and trying various different options, I was finally able to achieve what I want using the [importrange](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) function.

At first, I tried using a combination of hide columns & protect range, but this wouldn't work because a simple copy & paste would reveal the contents of the hidden columns.

Solution: The 'master' spreadsheet does not have any sensitive column data and can be shared with everyone in the organization... I then **ADD** the sensitive data to a new spreadsheet and use importrange to grab contents from the 'master'. (Previously I had the roles reversed, but this didn't work)

---

You may want to add unique keys per row entry so that sorting etc won't mess things up when you zip-up the sensitive data and the 'master' data.

Comment: What if the person you are protecting the sensitive data from simply alters the importrange function?  Wouldn't they be able to import any column they choose?

Comment: @jbright yes, of course they could - but the 'new spreadsheet' with the importrange function is (in my case) only for my use :)

Comment: @lee Hi, Lee. I've the very same need. It would be very kind from you if you could share some more detail about how you manage to "zip-up" the sensitive data with 'master' data by means of a unique row id.

Comment: Maybe this can help, same solution but more detailed https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-hide-tabs-from-specific-people-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 10):

I came here looking for a way to share only certain columns of a spreadsheet with a customer, but not all.

As noted in the other answer, using [=IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) works well, but a clever customer could simply edit the function and see the other columns.

My solution was to first create a 'proxy' spreadsheet that imported only the columns I want the customer to see. This proxy spreadsheet is not shared.

Then, I created *another* spreadsheet that imported the columns from the proxy, and shared *that* spreadsheet with the customer. This way, even with edit privileges, it's impossible for him to see anything that isn't on the proxy spreadsheet.

A bit clunky to be sure, but it worked perfectly for my situation.